# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.richfaces.renderkit.AjaxCommandRendererBase.isSubmitted

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I've the following JSF 2 + RichFaces 4 code:

```
<h:form>
     <rich:panel>
         <h:commandLink id="exportLink" 
                 action="#{MyMBean.execute}"
                 value="Do"
                 style="padding-right: 5px"/>
     </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

`MyMBean.execute` returns `void`. When I submit the form, the following exception is thrown:

```
10:34:33,265 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web-client].[Faces Servlet]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8443-11) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AjaxCommandRendererBase.isSubmitted(AjaxCommandRendererBase.java:83) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AjaxCommandRendererBase.doDecode(AjaxCommandRendererBase.java:59) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.decode(RendererBase.java:80) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:793) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1187) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:925) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.as.jleo.web.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:73) [jleo-web-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.as.jleo.web.license.LicensesFilter.doFilter(LicensesFilter.java:77) [jleo-web-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.as.jleo.session.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:52) [jleo-web-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.as.jleo.login.SecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(SecurityCheckFilter.java:81) [jleo-web-client-web-mbean-2.00.00_beta.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:499) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
10:34:33,270 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web-client].[Faces Servlet]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8443-11) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in RichFaces which manifests when you mix `<a4j:commandXxx>` with `<h:commandXxx>` in the same `<h:form>` (the code in your question was thus not a true [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at all...). This is already reported to RichFaces as issue [13018](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13018) and [13647](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13647). For RichFaces 4.x, it's fixed in RichFaces 4.3.8.

So, you just need to upgrade RichFaces to at least 4.3.8.

Comment: Where can I download RichFaces-4.3.8? The RichFaces website only offers version 4.3.7.